# Apache Ignite : SQLQuery doesn't seem to work for as expected TouchedExpiryPolicy

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

We set the TouchedExpiryPolicy to 10 seconds and we expected the cache content to be available as long as there is a access gap of 10 seconds or less. And the content should be expired after 10 seconds of non-usage.

But we find that the cache content is being removed at the 10th second mark after creation even when the the sqlQuery is accessing the data prior to the 10th second. It works fine if we use a scanQuery or cache.getAll. And it fails for sqlQuery().

Is it possible that the TouchedExpiryPolicy/getExpiryForAccess (JPA Method for setting cache access time) is not working for sqlQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, SQL `SELECT` indeed seems to work without updating the access-based TTLs. Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7687 for that.